# Как получить текст элемента, который появляется при наведении

Tags: python, selenium, requests

Делаю парсер на Python, необходимо брать текст с объекта, который появляется при наведении. Вот [ссылка](https://wiki.cs.money/ru/stickers/sticker-ablej-katowice-2019) на сайт. При наведении на график появляется окошко, на котором указана цена. Её мне и нужно получать. Попытался сделать это с помощью Selenium. Накидал такой код, но скрипт зависает (скорее всего не может выйти из цикла while True). Код:

```
driver.get('https://wiki.cs.money/ru/stickers/sticker-ablej-katowice-2019')
while True:
    try:
        csmoney_svg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.line-chart > rect:nth-child(2)')
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(csmoney_svg)
        csmoney_sticker_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        print(csmoney_sticker_price)
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

Импортирую:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Сам селениум инициализирован, путь и настройки прописаны правильно. Элементы на странице есть, проверял. Нужно как-то "удержать" импровизированный курсор на графике. И ещё, по этой же теме, можно ли как-то назначить чтобы курсор наводился в один из углов? Так как справа самые новые цены, нужно получать именно их.

Если будет удобнее и правильнее сделать через requests, не откажусь от помощи. Как я понимаю, нужно отправлять post запрос и получать данные графика. Но как его отправлять правильно я не знаю. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Спасибо

Comment: Это в принципе можно сделать. Проэмулировать событие от мыши джаваскриптом. Ненадежно это (неясно какому элементу посылать, с координатами пляски), уж очень много чего может сломаться легким движением руки программиста того сайта. Лучше уж выполнять запросы те, которые страница делает и вытаскивать оттуда сырые данные. И быстрее будет гораздо работать, т.к. браузер и селениум не нужен, достаточно `requests`

Comment: сделайте пост запрос на https://wiki.cs.money/graphql, вернется json с данными для графика

Comment: @Jack_oS не работал с post запросами, можете помочь с ним? Как я понимаю, нужно указать параметры что б получить именно тот график, который мне нужен

Comment: да, нужен параметр name_ids, для  sticker-ablej-katowice-2019 отправляет variables: {name_ids: [194870]}, например... никак не найду, где он их берет

Comment: @Jack_oS а как вообще прописывать post запрос? В плане передачи параметров и т.д. Спасибо

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: @Roman Konoval а как это сделать с помощью requests? Человек ниже писал, но я плох в post запросах, поэтому не понял каким образом его отправить и получить значения. Касательно синтаксиса разобрался, но не понимаю в каком виде передавать параметры и т.д. Буду благодарен,если напишите как сформировать запрос конкретно для моей задачи. Спасибо

Comment: Тут ответ про requests будет вообще не по теме вопроса. Нужно либо этот поменять либо новый создать, чтоб описать что не получается или не ясно с requests.

Comment: @Roman Konoval изменил вопрос. По итогу, мне нужно любым удобным и правильным способом получить информацию с графика. Посмотрел через браузер, в этом post запросе как раз есть информация, которая мне нужна, при чем в удобном формате. Буду благодарен за помощь в формировании запроса